# Test for multivariate regression coefficients

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, multivariate-regression

Given a multivariate regression, how can I test if each element in the coefficient matrix is statistically significant? Would doing a t-test be right?
$$\mathbf{Y}=\mathbf{X}\mathbf{B}+\mathbf{E},$$
where $\mathbf{Y}, \mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{E} \in R^{n\times m}$ $(n>m)$ and $\mathbf{B}\in R^{m \times m}$. You can treat each column of $\mathbf{Y}$ and $\mathbf{X}$ as a time series.

I found [this](http://users.stat.umn.edu/%7Ehelwig/notes/mvlr-Notes.pdf) where it goes through multilinear regression (p.43) and also goes through inferences about the coefficient (p.75). But it considers each row of the coefficient in the test. My question is about testing each element of the coefficient to see if it is significant.

Comment: How can you test it if Y is univariate? (It is a time series!)

Comment: Each $\textbf{column}$ can be treated as a time series; rows representing the date points and columns are the variables. @MichaelM

Comment: Yes. How would you test if Y would only have one column, i.e., would represent only one time series?

Comment: I believe a t-test would work for multiple linear regression. $t=\frac{\hat{B}_j}{se(\hat{B}_j)}$ @MichaelM

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding this correctly, a t-test with Bonferroni correction to adjust for multiple comparisons should work.

Comment: Could you elaborate?